# How to configure log4net to print to console in debug mode

Tags: c#, debugging, log4net, log4net-configuration

Is there a way to configure log4net to print logs both to console and to files during debug?

I am trying to find a way to debug my software efficiently by observing the logs immediately when they happen.

Writing to files is problematic for me for debugging because I don't want to wait until the file is flushed to the disk and then to open it.

Therefore I prefer it to write into console.

What do you suggest?

I added the `app.config` file with the additional appended, but I am not being able to show result console.

Following is my app.config configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IProviderService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8081/AP2" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IProviderService" contract="IProviderService" name="WSHttpBinding_IProviderService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
   <log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\\Temp\\1.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: could you post all your configuration ?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You need to have both appenders declared in your `<root>` section.

Configure your log4net like this:

```xml
<log4net>
    <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level: %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="Log.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="false" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="50MB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level[%logger]: %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />        
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Comment: actually, I was having a different problem, and the 2 top answers here helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898218/log4net-not-working

Comment: For Web API, use log4net.Appender.TraceAppender instead of log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764159/log4net-wont-log-to-console-winforms-app.

Answer (score 20):

It looks like you've forgotten to hook your appender up to the root logging:

```xml
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</root>
```