# Console Output In Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, console, log4net-appender

I had created a web application in .net framework. and for logging, I had used log4net package which I configured in the Web.config file.

Here is the code regarding the appenders used in the code.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="ManagedColoredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ManagedColoredConsoleAppender">
      <mapping>
        <level value="FATAL" />
        <foreColor value="Red" />
        <backColor value="White" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <foreColor value="Red" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="WARN" />
        <foreColor value="Yellow" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <foreColor value="Cyan" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <foreColor value="Green" />
      </mapping>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" />
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\\Talent App\\log\\TalentApp\\talentApplogs.csv" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="30" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{dd-MMM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss:fff},[%thread],%level,%logger,%message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="ManagedColoredConsoleAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Using these appenders I am successfully able to generate the code in files but I am unable to see anyout
on Console. Is there any way that I can see an output in both places.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am unable to see on Console - Do you means console tab of Developer Tool wizard?

Comment: "Here is the code regarding the appenders used in the code" <- you forgot this

Comment: @gandalf - you can just flag the question and select the duplicate and that comment/link gets generated for you, just FYI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure log4net to print to console in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374556/how-to-configure-log4net-to-print-to-console-in-debug-mode)

Comment: I need to see  the logs in the output window which is generated at the time when a web application is running

Comment: A web application does not magically generate an "output window". what exactly are you talking about?