# Log4net not printing to console in wpf

Tags: wpf, log4net

I have a WPF application with 2 log4net appenders in log4net, the first printing to file and the second should print to console.

For some reason I am not being able to show the result on log4net, but I do see it in the file. What is wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\\Temp\\1.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Header" value="[Header]\r\n" />
        <param name="Footer" value="[Footer]\r\n" />
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see a console pop up when you start the application.

It could be you have to configure your application as a console project to have a console window...

Otherwise  you can check trace info. Normally an appender tries to leave one error message there if he can't log to the desired location.

Output window of visual studio catches trace messages when debugging...

Possible duplicate:  [Log4net won't log to console (WinForms app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764159/log4net-wont-log-to-console)

Comment: It's a dup. Writing to console will not create a console in WPF.

Comment: no, i do not see console open. moreover, when i create new ConsoleApplication and use the same app.config, it is working fine. also, kenny - can you elaborate why it is not working in WPf?

Comment: Look into the other post for more info about showing the console even within a wpf application

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to see the messages in the output window in visual studio you should use the following instead:

```
<appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender" >
```

Comment: Will this show the errors of log4NET? I wouldn't think so. This will send your logging messages to the trace but it will not capture things sent to the trace.

Comment: This will only show internal log4net messages if you have debug set to true.  `<log4net debug="true">`

Comment: @Schwarzie2478 I'm not sure that he's asking to "show the errors of log4NET" anyway. I think he's wanting the log4net output to go to the output window.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call once `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` ?