# log4net console output with a web project

Tags: xml, console, log4net

I'm working on a web project and I wanted to use log4net. Mail, DataBase and RollingFile outputs are ok but not the Console. And I don't understand why.
Here is my code, is the problem comming from the fact that I don't use any console for my project ?

```
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%level] %message -- %exception %newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Where should a **console output** be in a **web project**?

Comment: The console purpose is just to get the log, I have the ''Output console'' but nothing about my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found my problem but didn't really understood why I have to do like this. Anyway it works thanks to : [Log4net won't log to console (WinForms app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764159/log4net-wont-log-to-console-winforms-app)

```
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%level] %message -- %exception %newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```